# Dropdown menus margin-bottom not working

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/JkhkJ/

This jsfiddle is what i have so far. I want the select (drop down menus) to be even with the images (the 1, 2, 3 next to them). i have tried using the margin-top and bottom tags but they do not seem to be working. any help? not any particle way is needed, just need the dropdown menus to be even with the numbers next to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
position: relative; top: -22px;
```

instead of:

```
margin-top: -22px;
```

That should do it.

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JkhkJ/1/)

Comment: @LiverpoolFTW Dude, this is NOT a good solution. Don't go the pixel-positioning way. Instead, let the browser handle the positioning so you won't have to mess once you decide to change the size of the 1,2,3 images.

Comment: @Birk Whatever, you do your ignorant markup. One day, you'll see why this is bad, young padavan.

Comment: @Birk Quote: "not any partic[ular] way is needed". If he doesn't care about a particular way, why not teach him to get his stuff right from the beginning? Any "particle" reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3xcbw/1/

```
.select_step_wrapper {
    height: 43px;
    width: 245px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.select_step {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    height: 43px;
    width: 200px;
}

#states_wrapper {
    background: url(http://unavit.com/images/oneLabel.png) no-repeat left center;
}

#schools_wrapper {
    background: url(http://unavit.com/images/twoLabel.png) no-repeat left center;
}

#buildings_wrapper {
    background: url(http://unavit.com/images/threeLabel.png) no-repeat left center;
}
```

It's probably not the best css code or practice out there, but it's working fine.

I've added classes to your select box and some wrapping divs, so it will be easier if you want to do this again without rewriting code.

```
<div id="states_wrapper" class="select_step_wrapper">
    <select id="states" class="select_step">
        <option>Select A State</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="schools_wrapper" class="select_step_wrapper">
    <select id="schools" class="select_step"></select>
</div>

<div id="buildings_wrapper" class="select_step_wrapper">
    <select id="buildings" class="select_step"></select>
</div>
```

And as last note, you should consider avoiding tables for menus and use ul li with some styling instead, also try to avoid inline css.

Edit: I broke your layout a bit and there are some text floating around, but I made this very quick as I have to leave ;)

Good luck